# How to place the text diagonally, but with the letters horizontally?

Tags: html, css, transform

I need to do this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39nCH.png)

I need to place, for example, an `h1` diagonally across the screen, but the letters must remain horizontally.

I'have tried closing every letter between `span` and `letter-spacing++`, then `transform: translateY++`, but it doesn't convince me because I think this solution will give me too many complications in order to keep it full responsive, which is one of my main needs.

I tried too with:

```
<h1>
 <span>E</span>
 <span>D</span>
 <span>C</span>
 <span>B</span>
 <span>A</span>
</h1>
h1{white-space:pre}
<--And then added padding-left to every single span.-->
```

But I think in this case, Google will read EDCBA and I need to write ABCDE...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can fix your first approach:

Use a transform `rotate()` on the parent `h1` to get the overall layout, then apply a separate transform to each letter (`span`) with the opposite rotation.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>D</span>
  <span>E</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Perfect! In fact, it was my first idea, if I am not mistaken the problem was that in that attempt I didn't put the inline-block display to the spans and I discarded it. Thank you for help :)